# Fail to add hook to a command when there is an extra group

Tags: expl3, hooks

Consider the following example. The code is trying to append something after `\mytest`. Strangely, when there is an extra group, the `\hook_gput_code:nnn` does not work. There is no error message, just that the compilation process never stops. Why would this happen and what should one do to make the hook work?

```
\documentclass{article}

% \def\mytest{\normalfont\bfseries Text} % works
\def\mytest{{\normalfont\bfseries Text}} % does not work

\ExplSyntaxOn
\hook_gput_code:nnn { cmd/mytest/after } { mymodule }
  {
    Some code
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mytest

\end{document}
```

Comment: Smells like a bug... I'll investigate in a bit.  Though I get an error `! Undefined control sequence. \@nnil ->\@nil` (bug either way)

Comment: This should fix the issue: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commit/8f99cdeb.  If you want a temporary patch: https://pastebin.com/raw/rhFLYRuN

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik With the temporary patch you provided, I'm getting `File ended while scanning use of \__str_case_end:nw`.

Comment: ...or two hours...  Try this one: https://pastebin.com/raw/NbYr715A

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you! You are really good at this :-) May I ask one more question: do you think if one can safely assume that this bug shall be fixed with TeX Live 2022, or do I have to carry the patch in my packages?

Comment: It will be fixed in the next LaTeX release (2022-06-01).  I already opened a PR for it: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/pull/796.  Please don't add that to a package :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Currently a package of mine fails to work without your patch. Before the next release, if the patch should not be added to the package, is there some better way than manually add the patch to the document each time?

Comment: Right now I can't, but I'll see if I find a workaround.  I'll get back to you

Comment: Sorry for the delay (I forgot about this).  The whole issue is that the code takes the first item in the macro definition (in this case the tokens inside the brace), and does `\string` on the first token, and expands the rest.  You can work around the issue by making the first item in the macro be a single token, for example `\def\mytest{\relax{\normalfont\bfseries Text}}`.  Since it seems to be a typesetting command, the `\relax` shouldn't be a problem, but you can use something else, like `\@empty`.  Depends on what exactly the command does

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you! I shall take this into account.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik As the new version `LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> pre-release-0` becomes available, can I safely assume that this bug has been fixed from then on?

Comment: Yes, it's fixed (thanks for spotting the issue, by the way).  I'll write an answer so this doesn't look like pending.  Also, the `pre-release-0` is a mistake in the banner: the correct version is `LaTeX2e <2022-06-01>` (soon to be `LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 1`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by a bug in an internal function that detects the type of a command (how it was defined;  this information is used to determine how to add the `cmd` hook).  The bug would cause a premature expansion of the code which could cause trouble depending on how it was defined.  This has been fixed for the 2022-06-01 release.

Here's the relevant pull request for whom it may be of interest: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/pull/796